# cant access $parent.$index in scope

Tags: angularjs

i can't display the value of ng-model in scope. "radiovalue[$parent.$index]" this piece of code does not return any values.
im getting the array from the php using angular

```
html:

         <div ng-repeat="question in set" ng-if = "question.type === 'multiple'">
       <div class="shadow">
         <ul>
           <li><div class="question">{{question.question}}</div></li>
           <div id="multiple" ng-repeat="choice in question.questiontype.choice"><input type="radio" ng-name="question.type" ng-model="radiovalue[$parent.$index.choice]" ng-value="choice">{{choice}} </div>
         </ul>
       </div>
     </div>


Controller:
 $rootScope.radiovalue = [];
  console.log($rootScope.radiovalue);

PHP:
structure of the array
      $json['questionid'] = $value['questionid'];
      $json['question']   = $value['question'];
      $json['type']       = $value['type'];
      $json['questiontype']['choice']['a'] = $valueb['mc1'];
      $json['questiontype']['choice']['b'] = $valueb['mc2'];
      $json['questiontype']['choice']['c'] = $valueb['mc3'];
      $json['questiontype']['choice']['d'] = $valueb['mc4'];
```

Guys new problem:
     the output of array length is not correct. it displays array length of 5   although it has 2 defined array elements. i have here the plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/RfmK0s3FZIR0qziultEJ?p=preview .

Comment: you haven't presented enough code here for anyone to troubleshoot the situation and identify which properties are in which scope.

Comment: @Claies updated it

Comment: cannot replicate your issue: http://plnkr.co/edit/kBTW4oGMXLhqamoeGyZN?p=preview, please update plunker and point me tou your problem

Comment: @Andriy thanks for the plunker. i fixed it there, my problem is caused by typo error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should it not be:

```
ng-model="radiovalue[$parent.$index].choice"
```

And secondly you can get `$parent.$index` only when you have a `ng-repeat` inside a `ng-repeat`... i.e `nested ng-repeat`... then it makes sense.

Comment: same result. it returns empty

Comment: Do you have a nested ng-repeat? to get $parent.$index?

Comment: thats a two ng-repeat.how can i get the value of the choices? do you have any idea?

Comment: You could use ng-model="radiovalue[question.questionid]" as your ng-model to capture the value

Comment: still i can't get the value. is this correct ng-name="question.type"? because they are not grouped. using $parent.$index works but how can i get that data in the scope?

Comment: I guess, you are doing it in wrong way... can you check this fiddle... which can help you... http://jsfiddle.net/spechackers/exas8djn/

Comment: i fixed the group but the ng-model still not working